# Adding a class when another is shown

Tags: jquery, css

So, upon uploading a file, a list is shown as below:

**Before uploading:**

```
<li class="container_without_file">
   <ul class="file_upload"></ul>
</li>
```

**After Uploading:**

```
<li class="container_without_file change_container_size">
    <ul class="file_upload">
       <li class="file_shown"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So `before uploading`, the top `li` container height is not set but pre-determined as a button (right now, it is not possible to change its css without affecting others).

Upon uploading, I want to make the height to 228px to accommodate the newly added file so it looks neat and nice.

Right now, the top `li` container does not change the height because it is a button.

**So, here is my approach.**

1. File is uploaded.
2. A new `li` is added with `class="file_shown"`.
3. Using jQuery, it detects that `class="file_shown"` is added.
4. A new class of `"change_container_size"` is added to the top `li`.
5. New css is added to that class.

My question is what is the jQuery to detect a new class then add a class to the top `li` with `container_without_file` ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no jQuery methods to detect dom changes.. you can look at [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Can you show us your upload code. You can  implement it just after upload.

Comment: If you are in control of the code adding the class then do your operation here... or you can manually trigger a custom event and have a listener listening to that

Comment: Please create a fiddle so we can help better...